# How to open fragments with navigation drawer and change title by recyclerview

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

i have created a `navigation drawer` with `recyclerview` and added `fragments` to the list of that `recyclerview`, but am getting exception that,

`unable to start activity, getting inflater exception`

I checked it but unable to solve it. Here is my code an exception logcat.

Please suggest me how to resolve it.

Thank you.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.sun.suni.design.fragments.AboutUS;
import com.sun.suni.design.fragments.Overview;
import com.sun.suni.design.fragments.Products;
import com.sun.suni.design.fragments.ReachUs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle sDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout sDrawerLayout;
    private SunAdapter adapter;
    private View containerView;
    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "navtest";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "user_learned_drawer";
    private boolean sUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean sFromSavedInstanceState;
    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,"false"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            sFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View layout =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
        adapter = new SunAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int posititon) {
                displayView(posititon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onLongClick"+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }));
        return layout;
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Products();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new AboutUS();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Overview();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new ReachUs();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.drawer_list, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer

            sDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(recyclerView);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }


    public static List<Info> getData(){
        List<Info> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] icons = {R.drawable.products,R.drawable.aboutus,R.drawable.blog,R.drawable.reachus};
        String[] titles = {"PRODUCTS", "ABOUT US ", "BLOG", "REACH US"};
        for (int i=0;i<titles.length && i<icons.length;i++){
            Info current = new Info();
            current.iconId = icons[i];
            current.title = titles[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId,DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        sDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        sDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!sUserLearnedDrawer){
                    sUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    saveToPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, sUserLearnedDrawer+"");
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                if (slideOffset < 0.5){
                    toolbar.setAlpha(1-slideOffset);
                }
            }
        };
        if (!sUserLearnedDrawer && !sFromSavedInstanceState){
            sDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
        }
        sDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(sDrawerToggle);
        sDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
           sDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
    }
public static void saveToPreferences(Context conrext, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue){

    SharedPreferences sP = conrext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, conrext.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sP.edit();
    editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
    editor.apply();
}
    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue){
        SharedPreferences sP = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sP.getString(preferenceName,defaultValue);
    }

    class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;
        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener){

        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null){
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        public  void onClick(View view, int posititon);
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.sun.suni.design, PID: 14593
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sun.suni.design/com.sun.suni.design.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.suni.design.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.suni.design.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 88473612 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
12-07 16:10:04.946 14593-14593/com.sun.suni.design E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
```

xml file

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        tools:context="com.sun.suni.design.NavigationDrawerFragment">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_drawer_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/cloudicalabs"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@+id/container_drawer_image"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Do you have any custom view in your layout ? It is saying error inflating unknown. Post your layout file

Comment: i have added plz check it

Comment: You are getting error on your xml layout, post your xml layout

Comment: i hav added check it